# How to use failFast in dynamic pipeline in Jenkins with catchError

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the below pipeline code in my project , I want to abort taskrun2 when taskrun1 fails, I did set fastFail option as true but it is not working. but when I remove catcherror it seems to be working . How can I make fastfail work with catcherror ?

```
node ('test-node') {
   Setup: {
        stage('Setup') {
          script {
           echo 'Setup'
          }
        }
      }
      taskfetch: {
        stage('taskfetch') {
          script {
            echo 'taskfetch'
          }
        }
      }
   stage('parallel-stages') {             
      parallel (
      failFast: true,
      taskrun1: {
        stage('taskrun1') {
          script {
            catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
               echo 'taskrun1'
                sh "exit 1"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      taskrun2: {
        stage('taskrun2') {
          script {
            catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
               echo 'taskrun2'
                sh "sleep 10"
            }
          }
        }
      },
     )   
   }
   taskfinal: {
     stage('taskfinal') {
        script {
        echo 'taskfinal'
       }
     }
    }
 }
```